# Showing Topological Equivalence b/w Multiple Definitions of Torus

Tags: general-topology

I am given the following three definitions of a torus:

(i) The space in $\mathbb{R}^3$ obtained by taking an upright circle and rotating it about some z-axis.

(ii) The product space $S^1 \times S^1$.

(iii) A quotient space obtained by gluing the edges of a square, as per the following partition:

$A = \{(x,y)\quad|\quad x,y : 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1\}$

$B = \{(0,y),(1,y) \quad | \quad y: 0 < y < 1\}$

$C = \{(0,x),(x,1) \quad | \quad x: 0 < x <1\}$

$D = \{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$

I have to show that each one is topologically equivalent to the other two by finding homeomorphisms. My shot at a homeomorphism between (i) and (ii) is as follows:

Take a unit circle and, as you sweep it over an arc with angle $\theta$. associate this angle with an open interval on $S^1$ of length $\theta$.

Not entirely sure how to approach the remainder of the problem. I'm even struggling with providing a more rigorous definition of the above "homeomorphism". Beyond that, a homeomorphism is a continuous bijection with a continuous inverse, so what would an open set even look like with regard to the first definition? It just seems to be such an informal way of defining a torus that it does not add anything to the other two definitions? What am I missing here?

Comment: If you want to be completely rigorous, for (i) you should define this surface of revolution via parametric equations.  Defining the homeomorphisms will be greatly simplified by using the well-known fact that a bijective continuous map between compact Hausdorff spaces is automatically a homeomorphism.

Comment: @SteveD but that's how the definition was presented. How can I define a homeomorphism with the given definition?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense: you want an explicit homeomorphism from an object that has no explicit definition? From (i), the best that can be done is to say "for a point $x$ on the circle, rotated an angle $\theta$, map that to $(x, \theta)\in S^1\times S^1$".